# leveldb - numeric indexing and paging

Tags: database, node.js, leveldb

I understand that with leveldb you can do ranged queries by key(start, end) but I am wondering if there are any clever ways that one can do a numerically ranged query as you can do with an sql query such using offset and limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use your key comparator instead of the default in leveldb.  The you can construct a start key by given numeric offset.